# Correctly displaying results from an ajax request to html

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I just made a simple request using JQuery's AJAX function that will be retrieving data when it's done requesting. This is my code :

```
('.submit').on('click', function(e){

  e.preventDefault();
  var tobesent  = $('input.test').val();
  $.ajax({
     type : 'POST',
     dataType : 'json',
     url : '<?php echo base_url("ajaxcontroller/submit"); ?>',
     data : {'content' : tobesent}
  })
  .done(function(data){
     $.each(data, function(k, v){
        $('div.placedhere').append(v.fullname);
     })
   })
   .fail(function(data){
     console.log(data);
    })
});
```

It worked very nice, it did receiving data. But the problem is, each time I click the submit button to make a new request, the retrieved results get appended to the end of the previous results.

I know it happens because the `$('div.placedhere').append(v.fullname)`.

How can I clean the div before I start making a new request so the div only shows the newest results?

I've done things like `$('div.placedhere').remove()` before `$('div.placedhere').append(v.fullname)` but the div only shows the last record from the retrieved data.

I had also tried to change the `append()` function to `html()` function, I've got the same result, the div only showed me the last record of the data.

How can I clean the div before I start making a new request so the div only shows the newest results?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I clean the div before I start making a new request so the div
>   only shows the newest results?

You can use [`.empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty)

```
 var div = $("div.placedhere"); // cache selector outside of `click` handler
```

---

```
 .done(function(data) {
   div.empty(); // remove child nodes of `div.placedhere`
   $.each(data, function(k, v){
    div.append(v.fullname);
   })
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by 2 way

**1)clear div before ajax call**

```
('.submit').on('click', function(e){

   e.preventDefault();

   $('div.placedhere').empty(); //clear div before ajax call

   var tobesent  = $('input.test').val();
   $.ajax({
     type : 'POST',
     dataType : 'json',
     url : '<?php echo base_url("ajaxcontroller/submit"); ?>',
     data : {'content' : tobesent}
  })
  .done(function(data){
     $.each(data, function(k, v){
     $('div.placedhere').append(v.fullname);
  })
}).fail(function(data){
     console.log(data);
  })
});
```

**2)use `HTML` instead of `APPEND`** (`html` makes div empty then appends new value)

```
('.submit').on('click', function(e){

   e.preventDefault();

   var tobesent  = $('input.test').val();
   $.ajax({
     type : 'POST',
     dataType : 'json',
     url : '<?php echo base_url("ajaxcontroller/submit"); ?>',
     data : {'content' : tobesent}
  })
  .done(function(data){
     $.each(data, function(k, v){
     $('div.placedhere').html(v.fullname); // use `html` like this
  })
}).fail(function(data){
     console.log(data);
  })
});
```